# is there a way of returning a bool value from db.Execute(sql) in C# mysql?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2019

I am fiddling around with some mysql commands and would like to know how I can return a bool if my command was successful, here is some example code...

```
    public static bool RunSQL(string SQL)
    {
        try
        {
            // Info: db is defined in my dependency service!
            bool execute = false;
            Console.WriteLine(SQL);
            execute = Convert.ToBoolean(db.Execute(SQL));
            db.Close();
            return execute;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GlobalErrorList.ErrorControler(ex.Message, "DatabaseManager", SQL, "RunSQL");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My issue here is that db.Execute(sql) always returns 0 even when the command is successful, this I have checked in my database, for example the sql string is a string that is defined to create a table, it works fine, but the db.Execute(sql) returns 0;

My question is... Can anyone help my find a reliable way of returning the value of the executed string?

I.E true if was successful false if not!

Comment: I believe that the method `Execute` is returning the number of affected rows, anyway check docs of the lib you use to connect to mysql to find out what is the return value of that method

Comment: @Phate01 will do thank you for the info :-)

Comment: It's just `SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(pathOfdbFile)` conn  gets returned!

Comment: You have to look at the method `db.Execute`, the `db` object doesn't seem of type `SQLiteConnection` according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0) since there is no `Execute` method

Comment: I think OP is using ```System.Data.SQLite``` rather than ```Microsoft.Data.Sqlite```

Comment: I am `using SQLite;` and as I mentioned, there is no problem sending my strings, adding data, or creating new tables, I just need to get a value back to return that to the hierarchy of my methods. So `If (RunSQL(SQL));  Do Something`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to return true or false when execute the sql sentence.

I used SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar() method to check it.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

```
class Program
    {       
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string sql1 = "create table scores(name varchar(20),score int)";
            string sql2 = "insert into  scores(name,score) values ('tom',90),('aya',97)";
            string sql3 = "delete from  scores where name='tom'";
            string sql4 = "select * from scores where name='tom'";
            bool a = p.operate(sql1);
            bool b = p.operate(sql2);
            bool c = p.operate(sql3);
            bool d = p.operate(sql4);
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        //Add, delete, modify, query and return results
        bool operate(string SQL)
        {
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, m_dbConnection);
            try
            {
                if (null == command.ExecuteScalar())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Jack, I will have a check of this tomorrow and let you know thanx :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, due to some unforeseen circumstances I have not been able to work on my app, I have just tested this and on ```SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL,  db);``` it says SQLLiteCommand does not contain 2 arguments..which sqllite are you using?

Comment: *which library are you using?

Comment: @Mark, I am using System.Data.SQLite. You can install it from nuget-package.